# Pop up Project Status Date form through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

What's the VBA code to popup the Status Date form in Project 2016? Just like if click the button on the ribbon. I want the code to pop up the Status Date and then keep running the macro.

Comment: You mean like using a `MsgBox`?

Comment: yes. Just like if I click the button on the ribbon.

Comment: Have you tried something simple, like `MsgBox ThisProject.StatusDate`?

Comment: That way shows me the set current statusdate, does not allow me to modify it.

Comment: You didn't ask for how to change it in the question.  See my answer...

Comment: sorry, the question was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim NewStatusDate
NewStatusDate = InputBox("Please enter a new Status Date value")
If NewStatusDate <> "" Then ' Check it's not empty
    ThisProject.StatusDate = NewStatusDate
End If
```

You'd probably want to validate that the value given was a date and any other things you might require but this will pop up an inputbox and allow you to change the Status Date for the project.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd just like something simpler. Can't I just pop up the actual form? Just like if I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I needed.

`ActiveProject.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("StatusDate")`

Answer (score 0):

While you can just pop-up the Project Information Tab with this line: `Application.ProjectSummaryInfo`, you don't have any ability to validate the Status Date. There's nothing to stop the user from just clicking OK or Cancel without entering a date.

It's better to call a function like this so you know that a valid status date was entered.

```
Private Sub GetStatusDate()

    Dim CurStatusDate As Variant
    CurStatusDate = ActiveProject.StatusDate

    ' set a default, suggested status date
    Dim SuggestedDate As Date
    SuggestedDate = Date

    Dim StatusDate As Date

    If VarType(CurStatusDate) = vbDate And CDate(CurStatusDate) >= SuggestedDate Then
        StatusDate = CDate(CurStatusDate)
    Else
        Dim Msg As String
        Msg = vbCrLf & "Suggested status date:" & vbTab & SuggestedDate
        If VarType(CurStatusDate) = vbDate Then
            Msg = "Current status date:" & vbTab & Format(CurStatusDate, "m/d/yyyy") & Msg
        Else
            Msg = "Current status date:" & vbTab & Format(CurStatusDate, "m/d/yyyy") & Msg
        End If

        Dim NewDate As String
        NewDate = InputBox(Msg, "Enter the project status date", SuggestedDate)

        If Len(NewDate) = 0 Then
            StatusDate = SuggestedDate
        ElseIf Not IsDate(NewDate) Then
            StatusDate = SuggestedDate
            Msg = "Your entry of " & NewDate & " was not recognized as a valid date." & _
                vbCrLf & StatusDate & " will be used as the status date."
            MsgBox Msg, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid entry"
        Else
            StatusDate = CDate(NewDate)
        End If
        ActiveProject.StatusDate = StatusDate
    End If

End Sub
```